# Code fails with stdin from SED

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I have a bash script that finds files with particular extension and then pass the files into a function that checks every line in the file for only files that contain a library imported. For example:

```
function testing() {
while IFS='' read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ .*log\" ]]; then
        echo "log is imported in the file" $1
        break
    else
        echo "log is not imported in the file" $1
        break
    fi
done < <(sed -n '/import (/,/)/p' "$1")
}

function main() {
for file in $(find "$1" -name "*.go"); do
    if [[ $file == *test.go ]]; then
        :
    else 
        var1=$(testing $file)
        echo "$var1"

    fi
done;
}

main $1
```

The problem is the script works without the else block in the `testing` function but with the introduction of the else block in the `testing` function it just defaults to echoing the `log is not imported in the file blah` even if `log` is used in some of the files.

Any idea(s) on what is the problem?

Thanks.

Here is a sample input file:

```
package main                                                           

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    logger "log"
    "net/http"                                                           
)                                                                        
type webPage struct {
    url  string
    body []byte
    err  error                                                              
}                                                                         
...
```

And the output is basically to echo if `log` is imported or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your effort in code tags, please do add the samples of inputs and outputs too in your post, you may get good suggestions too for them and it will be easy for us to understand your requirements too, cheers :)

Comment: In main, `$file` and `*test.go` aren't quoted at all. Is the if-branch to be interpreted empty? Parsing the output of *find* is rarely a good idea (problems with whitespace).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The if-branch is to do nothing if file that ends with `*test.go` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the logic of your `testing` function as it will only test the first line of the file. Indeed, each branch of the `if [[ "$line" =~ .*log\" ]]` has a `break` statement, so in practice, a `break` is reached whenever the first line is read.